# UWP lock scrollviewer in a position

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have a scrollviewer would like to lock it in particular scroll position in one action and have to release it in another action.

1. I have tried enabling and disabling `VerticalScrollMode` it alters the
   scrollposition.

> MyScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;

2. I have also tried changing `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` it brings the verticaloffset to top

> MyScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;

Would like to know is there a way to lock scrollviewer at a particular offset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written some code to test it, and it seems that it works. Maybe it will give you an idea how to solve your problem. You could simply lock the scrollviewer and then offset it to the item you want to display or simply disable scrolling 'later', becasue for me, it doesn't seem to change the view. If you add items dynamically, then VisualTreeView might help you further.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="200" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="SomeScrollViewer">
        <StackPanel x:Name="LotsOfItems" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <Button
            x:Name="OffsetButton"
            Click="OffsetButton_Click"
            Content="Offset" />
        <Button
            x:Name="LockButton"
            Click="LockButton_Click"
            Content="Lock/Unlock" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            LotsOfItems.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Some item in a scrollviewer: " + i.ToString() });
        }

    }

    private void OffsetButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SomeScrollViewer.ChangeView(0, 250, 1f);
    }

    private void LockButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SomeScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode == ScrollMode.Disabled)
        {
            SomeScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
            SomeScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;

        }
        else
        {
            SomeScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
            SomeScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really minimal and simple way of doing it, but maybe you can build upon it to achieve what you want.

```
public double offset = 0.0;
```

Save offset before you disable the scrollbar:

```
offset = ScrView.HorizontalOffset;
ScrView.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
```

Once disabled, add the offset value back to the scrollbar

```
ScrView.ChangeView(offset, null, null, false);
```